# Groovy 3 support in Eclipse Groovy Editor

Tags: eclipse, groovy, editor

I have installed the latest release of the Groovy Development Tools in my Eclipse 2020-12. As I try to use Groovy 3.0 features. for example, `do { } while()`, it is flagged as an `Unexpected Token` syntax error. The documentation says that this version does support Groovy 3. Is there perhaps a setting to set up the Groovy compliance level for the editor? My currently selected Groovy Compiler is v3.

Thank you!
Oleg

Answer (score 1):

The antlr4-based parser is not enabled by default. You can enable it by setting system property groovy.antlr4 to true. More details in the release notes of Groovy-Eclipse on github.

Comment: will it be reflected in upcoming groovy-eclipse versions so it works out the box?

Comment: Yes, you can track progress here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1011